# Undefined variable in include() under Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, variables, drupal-theming, drupal-templates

I have defined a function to return an array and need to pass this array as a parameter to a template (node--contenttype.tpl.php).

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {{
  $variables['tdata'] = $myArray;
}
```

In node--contenttype.tpl.php

```
print $tdata;
```

I tried to call the variable $tdata, but the error shows

> Notice: Undefined variable: tdata in include()...

The same error happens if I define a variable in template.php and call from node--contenttype.tpl.php.

Comment: It seems like this post might be helpful: [Where to declare variables common to different include files in a module - Drupal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6042617/751619)

Comment: Could you show us the code in your template file where you're trying to access the variable?

Comment: What's with the double brace `{{` on the function line? That's not valid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops... I think I see your problem now.

You should be using hook_preprocess_node(), not hook_preprocess_page() if you want your variables to be available in your node template files.

Make sure you clear cache after you make the change too!

Let us know if that fixed your issue...